# Approximating discontinous derivatives with continuous derivatives?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f(x)=|x|$, so that $f'(x)= \frac x{|x|}$. Let $g$ be a function with $$g'(x)=\frac x{\sqrt {x^2+\frac1c}}.$$ Then $\lim_{c\to\infty}g'(x)=f'(x)$. Both functions have the same domain, but $g$ is a little nicer: unlike $f$, it's differentiable over the entire domain for each $c$ in $(0, \infty)$.

Or to take another example. Let $h(x)=x^{\frac13}$, so that $h'(x)=\frac1{3x^{\frac23}}$. Let $l$ be a function satisfying $$l'(x)=\frac1{3(x^2+\frac1c)^{\frac13}}.$$ As above, $\lim_{c \to \infty}l'(x)=h'(x)$; $h$ and $l$ have the same domain, but $l$ is differentiable everywhere for each $c$ in $(0, \infty)$.

Is it always true that if $f$ is a function continuous on an interval $I$ and differentiable everywhere except for countably many points in $I$, then there exists a function $g$ which can be made to approximate $f$ arbitrarily well on $I$, but which is differential everywhere on $I$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for a very simple reason.  The Weierstrass approximation theorem says that any continuous function $f:I\to \mathbb{R}$ can be uniformly approximated by a polynomial function.

For any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a polynomial function $p_{\epsilon}$ such that for all $x \in I$:

$$|f(x) - p_{\epsilon}(x)| < \epsilon$$